# Why is the distance negative in a kinematic equations?

Tags: kinematics, projectile, rocket-science

A rocket with zero initial speed takes off at a speed of 100 meters per second, assuming that gravity is 10 meters per second squared, determine the distance travelled:

$$ v_f^2 = v_i^2  + 2ay $$

substituting the values:

Knowing that gravity acts in the opposite direction to the movement of the rocket, we have:

$$ 100^2   =    0^2 + 2(-10)y $$

$$ y = \frac{10000}{-20} $$

This results in a negative distance, can someone explain this to me?

The distance should be positive since the movement is positive!

Comment: I think you're switching your final and initial velocities? The initial should be 100, on the right-hand side of the equation, and the final is 0, which goes on the left-hand-side.  That fixes the sign error.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. You should take into account that this site has a strict policy about homework-like questions. I suggest you read about it in the help center.

Comment: Anyway, there is a conceptual issue related to your question. Kinematic formulae provide the $y$ *coordinate*, which is a quantity with a sign.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the initial and final velocity. You said the rocket took of at 100 m/s then the initial velocity must be 100 m/s.The velocity at the maximum height will give us $v_f=0$. Then we solve the equation $v_f^2=v_i^2+2ay$ by plugging in the values for v, that will give us: $0=100^2+2(-10)y$ that results in $-100^2=-20y$,  solving for y gives  $y=-10000/-20=500$. The maximum height to which the rocket will go up to will be $500$m. Your initial equation suggested that the rocket accelerate upwards from 0m/s to 100m/s, which is impossible, because you didn't mention any upwards acceleration. You got the negative y value of $-500$m because the rocket would have to travel $500$m downwards to reach a speed of 100m/s with the gravitational acceleration of $-10m/s^2$.